# How to recover my inclusion in google results after being penalized for receiving comment spam?

Tags: search, google, seo, search-engines

My website had very high search engine results, especially in Google.
But I left the website for a couple of months and didn't notice the comments were full of SPAM, about 20k comments of SPAM. Then i checked my google results and I'm out of google !
After years of having good results, no spam, how can I now recover from that?
The spam problem has been solved completely. No more spam, and the website is very legit and very nice.

Well, at least I think I was penalized, I don't see any other reason.

Comment: webmasters.com, SO's sister site for pro webmasters, is probably a better platform for this question

Comment: Thanks a lot for your feedback. I will just get there and ask the same question. Thanks.

Answer (score 9):

You should ask for it to google through [Google Webmaster Tool](http://www.google.com/webmasters/tools)  (first you must register your site, then ask for the reconsideration)

Comment: +1 Just dropping a link which provides a bit more info about reconsideration requests: http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?answer=35843

Answer (score 2):

I would clean up the spam and then ask for a reconsideration. I would also drop the auto post option add a quality bot spam filter.

Answer (score 0):

After the Panda Algorithm google check the content of your site also if you copied it from other websites then your site get penalized.