# My website was spammed and my ranking dropped by half

Tags: google, pagerank, spam

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to recover my inclusion in google results after being penalized for receiving comment spam?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/17040/how-to-recover-my-inclusion-in-google-results-after-being-penalized-for-receiving)

I put an update of my site live and I forgot to enable to comment approval queue. I noticed a few days later I was linking to spam and my Google rankings dropped by about half.

I have removed all of the links but I still have low rankings, Google has not crawled my spammed pages yet.

Is there any way I can speed up the process and how long will these links tarnish my ranking?

Answer (score 0):

Remove all these comments from your site. Then go to [google webmaster tools](http://www.google.com/webmasters/tools) and [apply for reconsideration](https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/reconsideration). Before you apply, make sure all the spam comments and the links are removed. Also get [reCaptcha](http://recaptcha.net) on your comment module along with [akismet](http://akismet.com) for your CMS or site. There are some other anti-spam filtering tools depending on your CMS. Making your comment section "**nofollow**" helps to *some extent* as this will prevent many bots from spamming your site.

Comment: Where exactly can I apply for reconsideration?

Comment: @Sam152, see my edited reply for the reconsideration link.